# How to neatly configure Spring WebSecurity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm currently working on setting up a reverse proxy security domain using Spring Security, and the idea is to require the bearer token on all the requests by default, except for a few exceptions such as signing up etc. Current my configuration function looks as follows:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

Ant matchers are pretty useful, but you have to pass all the URLs in individually. Is there a way for me to pass in an array of Strings instead so that I can keep the configuration separate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
```

In the above code `antMatchers` will accept string array also. Below is the implementation of anyMatcher method in spring security `4.2.3.RELEASE`. According to the method signature you should be able to pass a string array containing required paths.

```
    /**
 * Maps a {@link List} of
 * {@link org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher}
 * instances that do not care which {@link HttpMethod} is used.
 *
 * @param antPatterns the ant patterns to create
 * {@link org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher} from
 *
 * @return the object that is chained after creating the {@link RequestMatcher}
 */
public C antMatchers(String... antPatterns) {
    return chainRequestMatchers(RequestMatchers.antMatchers(antPatterns));
}
```

If you dig into implementation, spring is converting this args into a ArrayList of all paths.

Also, there is an alternate way. To Ignore the path which shall not be secured by spring security if you are extending spring's `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`class, override same method again.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("path":);
}
```

I guess it is neat this way.

Comment: Thank you for this. It completely slipped my mind that the ... parameter doesn't just take in multiple strings, it takes in an array of strings too.